# Magento Upgrade to M2.1.3 stuck in loop

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade

I tried to upgrade to M 2.1.3 and was unsuccessful and found update was stuck in a loop repeating these lines below over and over. Does anyone have any ideas of what might be causing this?

The stack trace of the looping process showed the following constantly repeating:

```
stat("/chroot/home/babywitc/babywit.com/html/var/cache/mage--5/mage--
-516_Zend_LocaleC_en_US_currencynumber_", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0660, st_size=128, ...}) = 0

lstat("/chroot/home/babywitc/babywit.com/html/var/cache/mage--5/mage---516_Zend_LocaleC_en_US_currencynumber_", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0660, st_size=128, ...}) = 0

lstat("/chroot/home/babywitc/babywit.com/html/var/cache/mage--5",    

{st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=45056, ...}) = 0
open("/chroot/home/babywitc/babywit.com/html/var/cache/mage--5/mage--    
-516_Zend_LocaleC_en_US_currencynumber_", O_RDONLY) = 11

fstat(11, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0660, st_size=128, ...}) = 0
lseek(11, 0, SEEK_CUR)                  = 0
flock(11, LOCK_SH)                      = 0

read(11, "a:4:{s:4:\"hash\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"mtim"..., 8192) = 128
fstat(11, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0660, st_size=128, ...}) = 0
read(11, "", 8192)                      = 0
read(11, "", 8192)                      = 0
flock(11, LOCK_UN)                      = 0
close(11)                               = 0


stat("/chroot/home/babywitc/babywit.com/html/var/cache/mage--7/mage--      
-516_Zend_LocaleL_en_US_symbols_", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0660, st_size=329, ...}) = 0

lstat("/chroot/home/babywitc/babywit.com/html/var/cache/mage--7/mage-

-516_Zend_LocaleL_en_US_symbols_", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0660, st_size=329, ...}) = 0
lstat("/chroot/home/babywitc/babywit.com/html/var/cache/mage--7",   

{st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=45056, ...}) = 0

open("/chroot/home/babywitc/babywit.com/html/var/cache/mage--7/mage--
-516_Zend_LocaleL_en_US_symbols_", O_RDONLY) = 11

fstat(11, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0660, st_size=329, ...}) = 0
lseek(11, 0, SEEK_CUR)                  = 0
flock(11, LOCK_SH)                      = 0
read(11, "a:4:{s:4:\"hash\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"mtim"..., 8192) = 329
fstat(11, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0660, st_size=329, ...}) = 0
read(11, "", 8192)                      = 0
read(11, "", 8192)                      = 0
flock(11, LOCK_UN)                      = 0
close(11)                               = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of reasons for this. First there is a bug that has a workaround with the upgrade from 2.1.2 to 2.1.3 that is referenced [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6078).

I can confirm that commenting out the two IF statements (line 67 and 70) in file setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Cron\JobSetCache.php works.

Also, apparently my cron job for set up had a typo in it that the M2 setup did not catch.